# How to remove focus on form fields

Tags: html, css, forms

I have created a form and set focus to `none` but I am still getting the green box to appear and stay around each form field when I am testing.

Here is the form: https://secureforms.nextens.nl/TEMPLATE

I have already tried using:

```
*:focus {
outline: none;
 }
```

AND

```
input:focus,
select:focus,
textarea:focus,
button:focus {
outline: none;
}
```

But for some reason, this still isn't working.  Below is the CSS that I am using to style the form.

```
input[type=text], select {
   font-size:15px;
   width: 85%;
   margin: 8px 0;
   padding-left: 10px;
   padding-top: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
   display: inline-block;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   border-radius: 25px;
   box-sizing: content-box;
}
.elq-form select
{
   font-size:15px;
   width: 85%;
   margin: 8px 0;
   padding-left: 10px;
   padding-top: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
   display: inline-block;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   border-radius: 25px;
   box-sizing: content-box;
}

.elq-form radio
{
   font-size:15px;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 8px 0;
   display: inline-block;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   border-radius: 25px;
   box-sizing: content-box;
}

input[type=submit] {
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #337ab7;
   color: white;
   margin-top: 8px;
   margin-bottom: 8px;
   border: none;
   border-radius: 0px;
   cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
   background-color: #337ab7;
}
input:focus,
select:focus,
textarea:focus,
button:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

I just want the green highlighting around the form fields not to show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this in your css

```
.LV_invalid_field, input.LV_invalid_field:hover, input.LV_invalid_field:active, textarea.LV_invalid_field:hover, textarea.LV_invalid_field:active,
.LV_valid_field, input.LV_valid_field:hover, input.LV_valid_field:active, textarea.LV_valid_field:hover, textarea.LV_valid_field:active {
    outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this CSS in your template, you gotta remove it to get what you want

```
.LV_valid_field,
input.LV_valid_field:hover,
input.LV_valid_field:active,
textarea.LV_valid_field:hover,
textarea.LV_valid_field:active {
        outline: 1px solid #00CC00;
}

.LV_invalid_field,
input.LV_invalid_field:hover,
input.LV_invalid_field:active,
textarea.LV_invalid_field:hover,
textarea.LV_invalid_field:active {
        outline: 1px solid #CC0000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Dev-Tools, it is line 7 of your CSS that is causing the issue:

`.LV_valid_field,  ...`